figure from clickData in callback (python, dash) won't show in app.layout - data for fig comes from sqlite db
after hours of R&D I don't know what to do anymore - help please.
I feed a sqlite db with mqtt values from 700 meteorological stations. In my dash app I see the stations on an open-street-map. The clickData is evaluated within a callback and returns the tablename out of the customdata from the station clicked. My callback uses this clickData as input to render a plot with datetime as x and values as y. Unfortunatly the function doesn't return the figure to the layout. If I save the figure to a png everything is fine but this seems odd as a solution. On the localhost I just see the dummygraph for the px but no data arriving. What am I doing wrong?
#### callback for rendering a figure triggered by clickData on the basis of sqlite db
#####         Problem: figure seems not to arrive in the Output of the callback

@app.callback(
    Output('graph_stat1', 'figure'),
    Input('graph1', 'clickData')
)
 def display_click_data(clickData):
     if clickData is not None:
        source = clickData['points'][0]['customdata'][0]
        conn = create_connection('sqlite_mqtt.db')
        df = pd.read_sql(f'''select * from {source} order by val_datetime desc limit 100;''', conn,
                         parse_dates=True)
        x_dummy = df['val_datetime'].tolist()
        y_dummy = df['val_wl'].tolist()
        for i in range(0, len(x_dummy)):
            x_dummy[i] = dp.parse(x_dummy[i])
        conn.commit()
        pio.templates.default = 'plotly_white'
        fig2 = px.scatter(x=x_dummy, y=y_dummy)
        fig2.write_image("fig2.png")
        return fig
#####


Looks like a typo : code creates fig2 from clickData but returns fig.
